# Plotting a function graph with a range of acceptable values

Tags: plotting

Using simplification over the range of acceptable values and integration, I found a function that needs to be depicted on a graph. Please explain why the graph is not being built. (I wrote "Minus" because the function is initially negative.)

```
sigmaPhiEnd = 1

sigmaPhiBegin = 
 sigmaPhiEnd + (Kappa*Rho^2 - a^2)/((Kappa*Rho^2 + a^2)*Rho)*
    Integrate[sigmaPhiEnd, {s, Rho, BEnd}] // FullSimplify

MinusSigmaRho = 
 Integrate[(s*(a^2 + Kappa*Rho^2))/(Rho^2*(a^2 + Kappa*s^2))*
    sigmaPhiBegin , {s, Rho, B}] // FullSimplify

MinusSigmaRhoSimple = 
 Assuming[{a^2 + B^2*Kappa > 0, a^2  + Kappa*Rho^2 > 0}, 
  MinusSigmaRho // FullSimplify]

MinusSigmaRhoSimpleTemp = 
 MinusSigmaRhoSimple /. Rho -> a /. BEnd -> a BEnda /. B -> a Ba // 
  FullSimplify

MinusSigmaRhoTempNotSimple = 
 FullSimplify[
  MinusSigmaRho /. Rho -> a /. Kappa -> 1/(1 - 2*1/4) // 
   FullSimplify, {a > 0, B > 0}]

MinusSigmaRhoTempNotSimpleReplace = 
 MinusSigmaRhoTempNotSimple /. BEnd -> a BEnda /. B -> a Ba // 
  FullSimplify

MinusSigmaRhoTempNotSimpleReplace1 = 
 MinusSigmaRhoTempNotSimpleReplace /. BEnda -> 4 // FullSimplify

Show[Plot[MinusSigmaRhoTempNotSimpleReplace1, {Ba, 1.001, 4},
    PlotLegends -> {"SigmaRho"},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue},
    PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
    GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 0.1], Range[-10, 10, 0.1]}, (*{Range[
  1, 4, 0.1], Range[0,  2.6, 0.1]}, *)
    Epilog -> {Arrow[{{1, 0}, { 4.05, 0}}], Arrow[{{1, 0}, {1, 2.7}}],
     Text["B/a", {4, 0.1}], 
    Text["-SigmaRho/SigmaPhiEnd", {1.125,  2.6}], 
    Text[Style["1", FontWeight -> "Heavy"], {1, -0.05}]}]]
```

Comment: If `Plot` doesn't show anything then try `Table` to see some of the values you are trying to display.  This `Table[MinusSigmaRhoTempNotSimpleReplace1, {Ba, 1.001, 4,1}]//InputForm` should explain to you why you aren't seeing your plot. See if you can give it enough information so that it can tell whether all your `ConditionalExpression` are `True`. Assigning some value, like 2, to `a` looks like that would be enough to see your `Plot`

Answer (score 3):

Your expression "MinusSigmaRhoTempNotSimpleReplace1" contains a condition. If it is evaluated, it returns e.g.:

[image]

This is not a number that can be plotted. To remove the condition, you may use "Normal" like:

```
Plot[MinusSigmaRhoTempNotSimpleReplace1 // Normal, {Ba, 1.001, 4}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"SigmaRho"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, 
 PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
 GridLines -> {Range[-10, 10, 0.1], Range[-10, 10, 0.1]}, 
 Epilog -> {Arrow[{{1, 0}, {4.05, 0}}], Arrow[{{1, 0}, {1, 2.7}}], 
   Text["B/a", {4, 0.1}], Text["-SigmaRho/SigmaPhiEnd", {1.125, 2.6}],
    Text[Style["1", FontWeight -> "Heavy"], {1, -0.05}]}]
```

[image]